# Missing prerequisites for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce, prerequisites, visual-c++-2012

I've recently installed `vs2012` and I've updated my ClickOnce application. To be more precise, the first time I've opened my `C++ project` (on which depends my primary c# project) I've not updated it and everything worked fine. `VS 2012` was still able to see the Visual C++ 2010 prerequisite. Later on I've updated my project by changing the Platform Toolset to `"Visual Studio 2012 (v110)"` under `Properties->Configuration Properties->General`.

In the meantime I've installed even other `software` and now I discovered that I'm no more able to add the Visual C++ prerequisite to my project for the ClickOnce publishing. The `Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x64)` prerequisite is marked with a yellow triangle and it is missing. Ideally I'd like to update to `Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries x64 (and x86)`, but even this prerequisite is missing.

I guess it is due to the fact that in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` the corresponding package `(vcredist_x64)` is empty. I've also noticed that in the list of installed programs in the Control Panel I had `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64` and `x86` installed, both the Redistributable version and the Runtime version (I think they where installed previously with Visual Studio 2010), while I was missing the Visual C++ 2012 files. Hence I'm arguing that the Visual C++ 2012 didn't come together with Visual Studio 2012, isn't it? I've even tried to install the [Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) packages by downloading them and now they are listed in my installed programs 8only the Redistributable, not the Runtime version).

However the prerequisite is still missing. How can I solve this? I've even thought about manually copying the bootstrapper package for Visual C++ 2010 located in the...`\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` folder and changing it manually for C++ 2012 but I do not know what I should write in `product.xml` under `<MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product=?>`. It seems that the product GUID to insert this information can be obtained with Bootstrapper Manager, but this program is throwing a lot of exception and I do not know how to do it. As a second solution is it safe to simply copying the package for Visual C++ 2010 from `\\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Bootstrapper\Packages to \v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`?

Answer (score 3):

Go to \v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages and make sure you have the vcredist_x86 folder.

In that folder you should have an "en" folder, that should remain there, you are missing

1. product.xml
2. vcredist_x86.exe

You can download the required .exe from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266495&clcid=0x409

As for the product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

    <Product
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
      ProductCode="Microsoft.Visual.C++.11.0.x86"
    >

      <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
      <PackageFiles>
        <PackageFile Name="vcredist_x86.exe" HomeSite="VCRedistExe"/>
      </PackageFiles>
      <InstallChecks>
        <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{6C772996-BFF3-3C8C-860B-B3D48FF05D65}"/>
      </InstallChecks>

      <!-- Defines how to invoke the setup for the Visual C++ 11.0 redist -->
      <!-- TODO: Needs EstrimatedTempSpace, LogFile, and an update of EstimatedDiskSpace -->
      <Commands Reboot="Defer">
        <Command PackageFile="vcredist_x86.exe" 
             Arguments=' /q:a ' 
             >

          <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
          <InstallConditions>
            <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
            <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
            <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>

            <!-- Block install on Win95 -->
            <FailIf Property="Version9X" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="4.10" String="InvalidPlatformWin9x"/>

            <!-- Block install on NT 4 or less -->
            <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>

          </InstallConditions>

          <ExitCodes>
            <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
            <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
            <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
          </ExitCodes>

        </Command>
      </Commands>
    </Product>
```

Comment: Thanks, how about vcredist_x64.exe?

Comment: Noam's answer is correct, except that msbuild doesn't like two copies of the "xml version ..." line.
I removed one and I could run msbuild on a script to make a setup file.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a similar answer for the 2012 x64 vcredist, here's one I cobbled together that seems to work. Note the download link is
    http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x64.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<Product
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  ProductCode="Microsoft.Visual.C++.11.0.x64"
>

  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
  <PackageFiles>
    <PackageFile Name="vcredist_x64.exe" HomeSite="VCRedistExe"/>
  </PackageFiles>
  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}"/>
  </InstallChecks>

  <!-- Defines how to invoke the setup for the Visual C++ 11.0 redist -->
  <!-- TODO: Needs EstimatedTempSpace, LogFile, and an update of EstimatedDiskSpace -->
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="vcredist_x64.exe" 
         Arguments=' /q:a ' 
         >

      <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
        <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>

        <!-- Block install on any platform other than x64 -->
        <FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Value="AMD64" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" String="InvalidOS"/>

        <!-- Block install on Vista or below -->
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>

      </InstallConditions>

      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>

    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```