# How to include Visual C++ Redistribution with application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I've written a large C# 4.0 App in Visual Studio 2010. Some time ago I added the CEF framework (version 43.0.0.0) in order to utilize a web-browser inside my WinForms application.

If I run my app from Visual Studio, the browser runs correctly. However, upon using ClickOnce to deploy my app, it threw the following error: "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." Although all the CEF files are present in the bin\Debug folder. In fact I found a page on GitHub listing which files are required, and a careful check verifies that all are present in the executable folder.

[A list of required files can be found here:](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution))

One of the points made in the above article, are that the Visual C++ Redist files are required and asks in question 6. How do I include the Visual Studio C++ 2012/2013 redistributables on the target app?

It specifically states that CefSharp version 43.0.0 and below needs VC++ Version 2012. Therefore, I downloaded vcredist_x86.exe (the 2012 version) 
I created a package.xml and product.xml Bootstrapper files in the Microsoft SDKs folder. I included these as a prerequisite in Visual Studio 2010's Publish screen.

However, upon a ClickOnce deployment and an attempt to launch the CEF Web Browser, it immediately throws the exception "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I am at a loss as to what to do, in order to get the browser to work outside of my development environment, i.e., for the End-User to successfully use.
I've followed all the steps that I've found on line, both on Stackoverflow and Github for CefSharp. What else is required to get this working?

Please help!

Comment: First, you need to verify by manual deployment that the app runs with all of the presumed correct files present. Then, you need to verify specifically which files are not present when deployed with ClickOnce.

Comment: See answers to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14497382/126995

Comment: Hello Mark. I'm not clear by what you mean by "manual deployment." I require a ClickOnce deployment for Full-Trust. A FAQ on GitHub references: "For ClickOnce, see #1314 for some pointers and solutions other users have come up with." They state that some non-managed dll's need to be included, but I can't see what steps #1314 outlines. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)

Comment: Mark, do you know if the files in the CEF "packages" directory needs copied to the bin\Debug folder, or does Microsoft copy this somehow during deployment?

Comment: I'm closing out this post on SO, as I'm going to post this question directly to the CefSharp portion of the GitHub forum, as it seems more relevant to ask the CEF community about this issue, via those who are actively supporting the browser. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this addendum in case anyone working with CefSharp has run into the same issue, namely "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.". It turned out to be a ClickOnce issue. ClickOnce included all the "managed" resources, but did not include the unmanaged ones, i.e., cef.pak, cef_100_percent.pak, d3dcompiler, libcef.dll, icudtl.dat, etc.

If I right-clicked on References and attempted to browse to these resources to add them, Visual Studio complained about them being unmanaged and would not allow them to be added.

After working with the Microsoft ClickOnce and Deployment forum, it was suggested that I right-click on the project, Add > Existing Item and add them. Then set their Build Action to "Content" and Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always."

This allowed the resources to show up in Application Files... on the Publish tab. After another ClickOnce deployment, launching the Web browser was successful. No more complaints about missing files.